# Hadoop single node cluster error on

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu, hadoop

I've followed each and every step for installing Hadoop from this website
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10

All the steps go fine except the last step where I start Hadoop using `start-dfs.sh` and lot of errors come. Please help.
The errors are :

```
15/04/07 00:08:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]

localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied

localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory

localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-namenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-namenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-namenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out’ for reading: No such file or directory

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-namenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-namenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied

localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory

localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-datanode-tushar-VirtualBox.out

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-datanode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-datanode-tushar-VirtualBox.out’ for reading: No such file or directory

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-datanode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-datanode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]

0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied

0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory

0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-secondarynamenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out

0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-secondarynamenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

0.0.0.0: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-secondarynamenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out’ for reading: No such file or directory

0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-secondarynamenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory

0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-secondarynamenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out: No such file or directory
15/04/07 00:08:34 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user account doesn't have the correct permissions to the `/usr/local/hadoop` directory, so Hadoop is failing when trying to create its logs.  Try running `sudo chown -R <username> /usr/local/hadoop`where  is your username. To get your username, you can use the `whoami` command.

Comment: the previous problem got solved but now new errors are coming

Comment: start-dfs.sh
15/04/07 20:48:48 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-namenode-tushar-VirtualBox.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-tushar-datanode-tushar-VirtualBox.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 3293. Stop it first.

Comment: 15/04/07 20:49:04 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Comment: when i type jps only the following comes:
3293 SecondaryNameNode
3889 Jps

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. You don't need the native libraries to run - they are nice, but not required. As for the secondary name node process, it's still running as before. Kill it ( kill -9 3293) (or to make it easier kill all Java processes) and try again.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers .. one last question ...why are namenode, datanode, nodemanager and resourcemanager not showing.... as they had shown in the link that is supposed to show after typing jps.. but in my case ... when i type jps following shows...

tushar@tushar-VirtualBox:~$ jps
2593 SecondaryNameNode
2692 Jps